# How to use MVC MapRoute to match a filename extension w/o regards to the path?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, routes

I'm attempting to use MVC MapRoute to redirect any file with a specific extension no matter what the path info is - like so:

```
www.mywebsite.com/blah.xyz
www.mywebsite.com/whatever/hithere.xyz
www.mywebsite.com/test/morestuff/kittens.xyz
www.mywebsite.com/anything/everything/nothing/testing.xyz
www.mywebsite.com/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/alphabits.xyz
```

I created a routeBuilder and the MapRoute I have looks like

```
routeBuilder.MapRoute("", "{filename}.xyz", new { controller = "Custom", action = "SpecialRedirect" });
```

What I'm not sure how to do is to send ANY page/file request with the .xyz extension to a handling method, but, I'm not sure how to ignore the rest of the path.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like their is no way to do this, so I resorted to a bunch of these.

```
   routeBuilder.MapRoute("", "{filename}.xyz",
        new { controller = "Custom", action = "SpecialRedirect" });
    
routeBuilder.MapRoute("", "{a}/{filename}.xyz",
    new { controller = "Custom", action = "SpecialRedirect" });

routeBuilder.MapRoute("", "{a}/{b}/{filename}.xyz",
    new { controller = "Custom", action = "SpecialRedirect" });

routeBuilder.MapRoute("", "{a}/{b}/{c}/{filename}.xyz",
    new { controller = "Custom", action = "SpecialRedirect" });

routeBuilder.MapRoute("", "{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}/{filename}.xyz",
    new { controller = "Custom", action = "SpecialRedirect" });

routeBuilder.MapRoute("", "{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}/{e}/{filename}.xyz",
    new { controller = "Custom", action = "SpecialRedirect" });
```

If anyone has a better way (this does work, but, it's ugly to me), please answer.